# Transformar uma informação JSON em variável

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Estou chamando uma função em node.js e ela retorna um JSON:

```
{
  "pair": "BTCBRL",
  "last": 2280.0,
  "high": 2306.0,
  "low": 2205.0,
  "vol": 113.17267938,
  "vol_brl": 255658.20705113,
  "buy": 2263.0,
  "sell": 2279.77
}
```

Gostaria de usar somente a informação "buy" desse json, ou seja, quero usar assim:

```
var buy = "o que vim no json no caso 2263.0";
```

Comment: Este Jon é retornado em uma variável, certo? Então é só usar:
var buy = "o que vim no json no caso "+ data.buy;
onde data é seu json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vou tentar escrever de uma maneira bem didática, e não de uma maneira prática.

Json é uma string, mas se você atribuir a uma variável o mesmo se tornara um objeto, exemplo:

```
var informacoes = {
    "pair": "BTCBRL",
    "last": 2280.0,
    "high": 2306.0,
    "low": 2205.0,
    "vol": 113.17267938,
    "vol_brl": 255658.20705113,
    "buy": 2263.0,
    "sell": 2279.77
 }
```

então você pode fazer algo como:

```
var buy = informacoes.buy;
```

Então você pode conseguir manipular a seu gosto.

Answer (score 10):

Complementando as respostas já existentes, caso você tenha uma *string* e não um objeto, pode converter com `JSON.parse`:

```
var str = '{ "pair": "BTCBRL",  "last": 2280.0, "high": 2306.0, "low": 2205.0, "vol": 113.17267938, "vol_brl": 255658.20705113, "buy": 2263.0, "sell": 2279.77 }';

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/pRyKPz)**.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize `.` para acessar o valor da chave do objeto:

```js
var obj = {
  "pair": "BTCBRL",
  "last": 2280.0,
  "high": 2306.0,
  "low": 2205.0,
  "vol": 113.17267938,
  "vol_brl": 255658.20705113,
  "buy": 2263.0,
  "sell": 2279.77
}
var buy = "o que vim no json no caso " + obj.buy;
console.log(buy);
```

Answer (score 5):

Usa assim:

```
var buy = json.buy;
```

Você pode usar colchetes também:

```
var buy = json['buy'];
```

Onde json é a variável que contém o seu json.

Answer (score 5):

https://jsfiddle.net/0wL68po2/

```js
var objeto = {
"pair": "BTCBRL",
"last": 2280.0,
"high": 2306.0,
"low": 2205.0,
"vol": 113.17267938,
"vol_brl": 255658.20705113,
"buy": 2263.0,
"sell": 2279.77
 }
alert(objeto.buy);
```